# assembly language help code with negative numbers

Tags: assembly, tasm

i have here a short part of a calculator code. I want to ask for help on how to perform arithmetic operations with negative numbers.

Here's my code:

```
ASSCII_LOOP : MOV EDX , 0
                  DIV ECX 
                  OR DL , 30H       ;MAKE REMINDER ASSCII
                  MOV [ESI] , DL    ;PUT ASSCII IN ASSCII_NUM
                  DEC ESI
                  INC EBP           ;ADD ONE TO THE CHAR'S COUNTER
                  CMP EAX , 0       ;IF AX > 0 GOTO 
                  JA ASSCII_LOOP    ;ASSCII_LOOP

    CMP EDI , 0                     ;CHECK IF THAT WAS A NEGETIVE NUMBER
    JZ REST                         ;IF THATS NOT NEGETIVE GOTO REST
    MOV DL , '-'
    MOV [ESI] , DL                  ;ADD A MINES SIGN TO THE STRING
    DEC ESI
    INC EBP

REST :
    LEA EDI , ASSCII_NUM

    ;MOVE THE ASSCII CODE TO IT'S RIGHT PLCAE IN ASSCII_NUM
    ORDER_ASSCII : INC ESI
                   MOV AL , BYTE PTR [ESI] 
                   MOV BYTE PTR [EDI] , AL
                   INC EDI
                   DEC EBP
                   CMP EBP , 0
                   JA ORDER_ASSCII

    MOV CL , '$'           
    MOV BYTE PTR [EDI] , CL         ;AT LAST PUT A DOLLOR SIGN AT THE END OF ASSCII_NUM
```

This program checks if the input is negative or not, if negative then go to REST. I want to ask this following:

*what is the function of REST in this program?

*I want to ask for advice on how to start writing code in this program to perform operation on negative numbers. I already know about the 2' complement thing, what i want is the code for 2's complement, i just don't know where to start, how to start. I am really new to assembly programming. Hope you could help me.

Here's my tried code but it does not work, i put it separately for better understanding:

```
neg_num: 
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov ah, 0000h
  mov al, num
  NOT al
  mov bl, al
  adc al, 00000001B
  mov bl, al
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having WAY too much trouble with this, scarface23! x86 doesn't use 1's complement, so the example may or may not help. We use 2's complement because it "just works" (supposed to, anyway). Your latest code should give you a 2's complement (`adc` isn't really right), but it would be easier to just `neg al` - that's what it does.

The `REST` part of your first example just moves the characters you've placed at the "end" of the buffer to the "beginning" of the buffer. If you started your print position at the right place (`esi`), you wouldn't even need to do it.

Just before what you show, you did something like `test eax, 8000h` to determine if the number is negative. If it's negative, you `neg eax` and set a flag (`edi`) to indicate that we're going to want a minus sign. Since you're using 32-bit numbers throughout, I'd do...

```
test eax, eax
jns is_positive
```

Testing just bit 15 would work for 16-bit numbers, but you're using 32-bit registers/instructions here. Mixing sizes of numbers may be what's causing you trouble. Since you've got a perfectly good (untested, but I don't SEE anything wrong with it) 32-bit number-to-ascii routine, feed it 32-bit numbers. Or, I think your routine will still work if you switch to 16-bit registers throughout. Terminating your string with '$' gives me a clue that this might be 16-bit code. Using 32-bit numbers/registers/instructions will still work, but stick to one size for the numbers. I think you'll have less trouble.

In the part you don't show - getting numbers from the keyboard - if the user starts with a minus sign, skip over the minus sign and set a flag. Convert ascii to number as-is, and `neg ax` or `neg eax` at the end if the flag's set.

```
mov eax, 3
sub eax, 4
```

Now, `eax` will be negative - a 2's complement - just use it. If you wish to change it to a positive number, "flip" all the bits (`not` or `xor` with all ones) and add 1. (this works either positive-to-negative or negative-to-positive) That's how 2's complement works, but just `neg` will do it in a single instruction.

If you need to change the size of a number while preserving the sign, `movsx eax, al` or so will do it, but easier to stick with the same size,

There may be a gross error in your code that I'm just not seeing, but what you've showed looks pretty decent to me (except the `mov al, RESULT +1` part). I suspect the problem is elsewhere - perhaps mixing sizes of numbers...

Comment: ive been trying for almost 2 weeks now on how to solve this problem. I know it's worth the efforts: collecting datas, infos, advises, clues, hints but i still can't got it right. I'm still new to this language, it's hard but i am really interested to learn assembly. My goal now is to make this calculator work, I hope i can pass this one before the deadline. Thanks Frank for all the help including my past posts.

Comment: I hope you could me Frank, you are my only hope for now.cheers!

Comment: ive tried my best but it never worked for me. Maybe il just have to show you the whole code in order for you to understand me better. Please refer to this link http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/assembly/threads/447042/calculator-using-assembly-programming-windows-and-tasm .I hope ul have time to check this and you could pin point the problem why negative number doesn't work even suggestions and advises. Please

Comment: it not really working. it tried everything, just same result. negative numbers, too hard to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you an example of how to implement 2's complement to perform simple subtraction. I will use my own generic mnemonics to demonstrate how to accomplish this. You can then apply it to your assembly program.

We will follow the model of A-B =  A + (B( 1's complement) + 1)

Ok, so lets say we want to subtract the contents of Accumulator B from A  (A-B).

Let us assume our operand for our Accumulator A value is in place ([AccA]<-someValue).

First:  Grab the value you need from memory and store it in Accumulator B.

```
    MOVM   B   'Move contents of memory into Acc B   ([AccB]<-someOtherValue)
```

Second: Complement the value of B to get its negation

```
    CMPL   B   'AccB = -B
```

Third:  Move your 1's complemented value to some register for temporary storage

```
    MOVBR R0  'Move contents of Acc B to Register 0
```

Fourth: We want to load a '1' into the now available Accumulator B

```
   MOVB   #1  'Move a '1' immediately to Acc B  [AccB]<- 1
```

Fifth: We want to add the contents of AccB to RO, where our -B is stored

```
   ADDB   RO    ' This takes care of the (B(complement) +1 part of our model)
                ' The resulting value will be stored in AccB
```

Sixth: Finally, add AccA and AccB

```
   ADAB     'Mnemonic for "Add AccA to AccB, result stored in AccA"
```

This fulfills our requirement of A + (B(complement) + 1)

This is all assuming your architecture doesn't allow for a simple SUBA or SUBB command. Some processors have that built in, but since you are learning the mechanics of it, the above basic code structure hopefully paints a better picture for you.

Comment: You could then make a little subroutine out of this to handle multiple subtractions in your program.

Comment: seems like this is a bit confusing, but i got some ideas. I'm still far behind about what i really want, anyways thanks!